# Stuck while establishing connection lambda with RDS proxy in Nodejs with same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

I have created three security groups in the same VPC

1. For lambda-SG gave an inbound rule for RDS-SG, RDS-Proxy, RDS-Lamda with port 5432
2. For RDS-SG gave 3 rules same above,
3. For RDS-Proxy also gave the same rules

[image: Lambda Function throw this Exception]

when I went to the cloud watch of RDS-Proxy I got an Exception that is given blow.

**Credentials couldn't be retrieved. The IAM role provided with the ARN "arn:aws:iam::--------:role/service-role/abc" couldn't be assumed. Make sure that this IAM role is set up correctly for this use.**

I also mentioned the role policy for secret, rds,kms. I can not solve this error is there anyONe who can help me out that'll be much appreciated

Comment: What is the trust relationship of the role?

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::---------:role/service-role/abc",
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: And the role is supposed to be assumed by Lambda? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/ says rds.amazonaws.com should be allowed to assume it.

Comment: i am getting this error now."Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda"

Comment: Mhm, you can try adding both services, not entirely sure how this is supposed to work either. Just basically guessing, looking at the docs.

Comment: I have added both services but got --> Error: This RDS proxy has no credentials for the role of Postgres. Check the credentials for this role and try again.",